# Creating a function to loop through an existing dataframe and adding values to a new column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with the following information:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'School':['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
                        'Year':[2009, 2010, 2011, 2012})
```

```
df
School   Year
A        2009
B        2010
C        2011
D        2012
```

I also have a separate list of schools (e.g. `df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'School':['A', 'B']})`) stored in a different dataframe.

I want to create a function that will loop through the school column and add True or false to a new column if the school is in the list.

How do I do this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. To be easy to help you, please provide a minimal reproducible example! https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Explicit loops, and appending, should be a last resort in Pandas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the pandas Series `isin` method:

```
df['in_list'] = df['School'].isin(df2['School'])
```